# Free API to import address book from gmail yahoo aol and hotmail to web application

Tags: java, import, gmail, yahoo, addressbook

I am sweating since 3 days to import the address book from gmail, yahoo aol and hotmail. The user will login to web app and he will create an event and he should share the event details in the form of HTML mail with his friends, he should able to import contacts from gmail yahoo aol and hotmail and then send the email.Is there any free API available or plug in, its a javascript based web app and I am using servlets and mysql. Should I save all the email addresses in my database before sending the mail?
I tried socialauth, but I am not able to integrate with my web app.

Kindly help me since I am novice to web application development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very much possible to import contacts from gmail, yahoo and hotmail. The privacy restrictions are solved by first redirecting the user to the actual provider, for example the gmail website - and the user authenticates there and is then redirected back to your application. Hence a user NEVER enters his other passwords on your web app.

Do have a look at this demo of socialauth. 
http://opensource.brickred.com/socialauthdemo/

If you think this is something what you are trying to do, please feel free to file a specific issue regarding the problem you faced in integrating.

Comment: Thank you Mr Tarun I am using the same social auth library, but I am novice to struts. If you dont mind I will keep posting my issues here as and when I come across.

Comment: @Tarun Nagapl : hello I just tried whole api, but I am not able to understand where is "action.do" file? Can u just help me

Comment: Hi Jeevan. Are you using struts or pure servlet application. So if you are using servlet then action.do is nothing but your servlet mapping or in struts it is action mapping which is given in your application struts config file.

Comment: thanks a lot tarun i am novice to struts i have copied the http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSocialAuthDemo content to my eclipse project, when i click on any of the icons the apache tomcat says "servlet action not available" can I have your email id if u dont mind?

Comment: Jeevan, you can post your issues on http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/issues/list. I'll give you reply over there.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously, seriously doubt that those services are going to give anyone access to that data.
It'd be a serious breech of privacy laws unless it was the account holder, and noone I hope is going to be STUPID enough to give their account names and passwords to some random website, opening themselves up to identity theft and leaving the email service to be used as a spam relay.

If such things exist, it'll be paid for services offered by the providers using some sort of secure web service interface and you should be able to find out about that by searching their websites.

Comment: Let me explain u the scenario. there are many web applications which provides this, get the emailds from the email service provider and send the mail through my web app which consists of HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: "and noone I hope is going to be STUPID enough to give their account names and passwords to some random website, opening themselves up to identity theft and leaving the email service to be used as a spam relay."

You actually don't provide your password to the website. An authentication page pops up (belonging to the service being called) and it's then when you provide the password.